# add objects to arraylist from resultset

Tags: java, arraylist, resultset

I have a database with movies and I have movie as a class. I am tring to get the movies from the database loaded into my GUI, but i cannot seem to get them into my arraylist. I get a null exception and I don't see where I'm going wrong.

```
public ArrayList getMovies(ArrayList movieList2)
{
    movieList = movieList2;
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                databaseURL, user, password);
        Statement sta = con.createStatement();


        ResultSet res = sta.executeQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM MOVIES");
        System.out.println("List of Movies: ");
        while (res.next()) {
            Movie movie = new Movie();
            movie.setTitle(res.getString((String)"Title"));
            movie.setYear(res.getInt("Yearmade"));
            movie.setGenre(res.getString("Genre"));
            movie.setDuration(res.getInt("Duration"));
            movie.setActors(res.getString("Actor"));
            movie.setDirector(res.getString("Director"));
            movieList2.add(movie);
        System.out.println(movie);
        }
        res.close();
        sta.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println(movieList2);
    return movieList2;
}
```

This is output from the stacktrace
run:

```
List of Movies: 
Exception: null
null
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

public static void main(String[] args) {
    controller.getMovies(movieList);
}
```

Comment: post the stack trace

Comment: Please include the error stack in your question.

Comment: run:
List of Movies: 
Exception: null
null
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: is movieList2 passed as null?

Comment: what is `movieList ` here `movieList = movieList2`

Comment: Have you initialized movieList2 ? what is the type of movieList ? Post the caller & stack trace. Try initiializing, movieList2 = new new ArrayList();

Comment: Replace `System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage()); ` by `e.printStackTrace();` it will show on what line it crashes (well everyone has found it's on `movieList2.add(movie);` because movieList2 == null).

Comment: movieList is an arraylist with movies, defined in the top of the class

Comment: List of Movies: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
null
 at Controller.Controller.getMovies(Controller.java:80)
 at Controller.Controller.main(Controller.java:27)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)


I now know why i get null point. i run the method with the empty arraylist movieList, but how do i get it to run with the list made in the method?

Comment: First debug it stand alone by changing caller as
public static void main(String[] args) {
 movieList =  new ArrayList();
    controller.getMovies(movieList);
}

and 
Removing below line in getMovies method
movieList = movieList2;

Comment: @user3498874 that's it, i got it working now. if you make an answer i will accept it!

Comment: Given it in answer section now.

Answer (score 1):

```
Initialize movieList in caller as below,
public static void main(String[] args) {
 movieList = new ArrayList(); 
controller.getMovies(movieList);
 }  

and Removing below line in getMovies method 
 movieList = movieList2;
```

Comment: it is more like a comments

Comment: Please convert his to a comment